Cython hello world returns segmentation fault
I'm trying to use the .so file generated by cython in my cpp file but it gives me a segmentation fault error.
So, I have this code into a test.pyx file:
#distutils: language=c++
#cython: language_level=3

cdef public void teste():
    print("helloooooo")

I'm compiling using this setup.py file:
from setuptools import setup, Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize
import numpy 

ext_modules = [
    Extension('teste',
              sources=['teste.pyx'],
              language='c++',  # Se você estiver usando C++
              include_dirs=[numpy.get_include()]  # Se seu código usar numpy
              )
]

setup(
    ext_modules=cythonize(ext_modules)
)

The command I'm using is: python3 setup.py build_ext --inplace
And it generates a .so file. Right, I have a c++ project which I would like to use to run this .so lib, so in my cmake file I have these lines to properly link the library:
link_directories(/home/.../cython/) #I'm using the full path right now because I was trying to make sure that it wasn't the problem


add_executable(cythontest tests/cython/testCython.cpp)
target_link_libraries(cythontest cythonmethods ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES}) #cythonmethods is the .so lib, I'm actually changing the name after it is generated

And, finally, in my testCython.cpp:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Python.h>

extern void teste();

int main() {
    Py_Initialize();

    teste(); 

    Py_Finalize();

    return 0;
}

when I run the cythontest executable generated by cmake it just returns a Segmentation fault (core dumped). I'm new to cython so I don't really know if I'm doing something wrong and I haven't found much information about how to use this .so file in c++ and especially with cmake, so if anyone could help please

You haven't imported the module/called the module init function. This is in the documentation https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/external_C_code.html#public-declarations
